# Change opacity for texture or sprites in XNA

Tags: xna

Is there a way to change the opacity or transparency for a texture or sprite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can make a semi-transparent version of any colour by multiplying it by a floating point number. For example:

```
Color halfOpacityWhite = Color.White * 0.5f;

spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, Vector2.Zero, halfOpacityWhite);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

You need to use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433698.aspx) overload of the SpriteBatch (or another overload that has the blend state option) with the blend state set to the [Alpha Blend blend state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.blendstate.alphablend.aspx). Then in the [SpriteBatch.Draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433986) method use a white color with the alpha (transparency) value you would like to have. You can use the Color.FromARGB() method to construct a semi transparent white color.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `BlendState.AlphaBlend` is the default, so you don't need to specify it. And that `Color.FromARGB` (as far as I can tell) doesn't exist. I think you might have meant `FromNonPremultiplied` (noting that the default `AlphaBlend` blend mode requires colours to be in premultiplied format).

Comment: Andrew is totally right, I've worked mostly with XNA 3 so I keep forgetting about premultiplied colours.